# ZeroMQ PUB/SUB with epgm not able to receive messages sent by process on the same host

Tags: c++, zeromq, multicast

All my processes have two sockets, one PUB and one SUB, and they all use the same multicast address and port.

For example, PUB will do this:

> bind("epgm://239.192.1.1:5555")

SUB will do this:

> connect("epgm://239.192.1.1:5555")
>      setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0); //subscribe everything

PUB will then send message by calling zmq_send, and SUB will receive by calling zmq_poll and do Nonblocking zmq_recv.

It works perfectly fine when I run two processes on two different hosts. But if I run them on the same host, the send works but recv never receives anything.

I know the send works because if I have the third process run on a different host I'll receive message from both of the first two processes, while the first two processes only receive message sent by the third process.

So I wonder is this because zeromq (or openpgm) does some kind of filtering so messages sent from the socket with same host:port as receiving socket will not be passed to receiving socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect ZeroMQ is not enabling multicast loopback, or maybe you are supposed to do it yourself somehow via the ZeroMQ API and you aren't.

Comment: I think disabling loopback is preferable, but isn't loopback meant for messages sent by the same process? My problem is between different processes.

Comment: No, loopback is to the current host, not the current process.

Comment: i see, there was a socketopt ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP, which used to enable loopback by default. But this option has been removed in version 3:
https://raw.github.com/zeromq/zeromq3-x/master/NEWS


`* ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP removed. There's no support for multicast over
  loopback any more. Use IPC or TCP isntead.`

Comment: Haha, the opinionated obtrusiveness of ZeroMQ authors is mind boggling. *"People will get confused, so we [remove](http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2010-June/004133.html) this functionality."*. Now there is no way to test epgm on same host. Excellent job.

Answer (score 0):

use NORM instead of PGM -> http://zeromq.org/topics:norm-protocol-transport - works well with loopback

Comment: Please check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Add more details than a link

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a 
specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some 
sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.